# Fill an object in Golang

Tags: go

How can I fill the todos-Object with a for-loop?

```
type Row struct {
    Name      string
    Completed bool
    Due       time.Time
    Rcount    string
}
type Rows []Row
todos := Rows{
        Row{Name: "Write presentation"},
        Row{Name: "Host meetup"},
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by fill?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you only want two Rows with the names "Write presentation" and "Host meetup" why would you want to use a loop?

Comment: I have a SQLite object and would like share the rows from SQL to todos->Rows->Row(here) of course with the result.next() for-loop from sql-object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the builtin function [append](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append)

Note that it is normally used in combination with an assignment, because it may have to allocate additional memory. A zero value slice works just fine, no need to call make.

```
steps := []string{"write program", "???", "profit"}

var rows []Row
for _, tasks := range steps {
  rows = append(rows, Row{Name: tasks})
}
```

If you want to loop over a sqlite3 query result, your loop will look different, but the `x = append(x, ...)` pattern will stay the same

If you know in advance how big your slice is going to be, explicit initialization with [make](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make) will be more efficient.

```
var rows = make([]Row, len(steps))
for i, tasks := range steps {
    rows[i] = Row{Name: tasks}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little hard to follow but try starting out with something following this pattern (error handling omitted for brevity):

```
rows, _ := db.Query(string, args...)
var Rows []Row
for rows.Next() {
    var r Row
    rows.Scan(&r.Name, &r.Completed, &r.Due, &r.Rcount)
    Rows = append(Rows, r)
}
```

If you can clarify the question perhaps we can provide better answers